# Why doesn't this below code move file from one location to other

Tags: c#

```
string source = textbox1.text;
string destination = textBox2.Text;
bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(source);
if (exists)
{
    // its create directory to destination
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destination);
    //  when directory creates it moves it
    System.IO.Directory.Move(source, destination); 
}
// File Not found exception unhandled
```

Comment: Are you sure this code raises that exception? if so, on what line? Also `CreateDirectory` isn't needed

Comment: * Do you give the textboxes the full path of directories?
* You don't need to create destination directory

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is fairly clear on this:

> This method creates a new directory with the name specified by *destDirName* and moves the contents of *sourceDirName* to the newly created destination directory. If you try to move a directory to a directory that already exists, an `IOException` will occur.

You're explicitly creating the destination directory before calling `Move`, so you *will* get an `IOException`.

Just get rid of the `CreateDirectory` call. That will at least allow it to *potentially* work - if you're actually getting a `FileNotFoundException` (you don't say so, but I guess that's what the comment is meant to say) then that suggests that `source` can't be found... although as noted in comments on this answer, that *should* be raising `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Comment: Whilst I agree, I'm not sure it raises a "File Not Found" exception (Directory not found?), which makes me think the actual error is else where.

Comment: @Sayse: Mmm, true. It does raise `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Let's see whether the OP gives any details...

Comment: @baberyounis: That doesn't give us any more information. The fact that your question is *just* code really doesn't help. Please edit the question to give more details.